# Как создать html-документ в C# программно

Tags: c#, html

Не могу найти в инете, в том числе и на MSDN, практическое руководство по созданию с нуля html-документа программно. Для начала мне нужно создать простой HTML-файл со всеми тегами, при открытии которого в браузере выйдет простое слово "Привет". Причем для создания хочу использовать классы `HtmlDocument` и `HtmlElement`, но никак не получается. Подскажите, где об этом подробно с примерами почитать или если, не затруднит, приведите простой пример, описанный выше.

Comment: - То есть, вы действительно уверены, что класс, который мейнтейнится уже 6 лет - он кривой и **только вы** это заметили?

- По существу - возьмите какой-нибудь [`template engine`](http://razorengine.codeplex.com/) и все станет тривиально.

Comment: Спасибо! Действительно ответ по существу! Прошу написать это не в комментах, а сделать как ответ. А то не могу коммент отметить как правильный ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по ответам, не руки у меня кривые, а .NET кривой в работе с классами HtmlDocument и HtmlElement. Выход из данной ситуации для меня оказался написанием своих собственных классов MyHtmlDocument и MyHtmlElement, выполняющих свои функции корректно. Надеюсь в .NET4.5 это исправлено...

Comment: для генерации html можно использовать Razor, который входит в asp.net

Answer (score 3):

Самый простой вариант - сохранить текст с расширением .html

```
//Write text to file
StreamWriter streamwriter = new StreamWriter(@"D:\index.html");
streamwriter.WriteLine("<html>");
streamwriter.WriteLine("<head>");
streamwriter.WriteLine("  <title>HTML-Document</title>");
streamwriter.WriteLine("  <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" />");
streamwriter.WriteLine("</head>");
streamwriter.WriteLine("<body>");
streamwriter.WriteLine("Привет");
streamwriter.WriteLine("</body>");
streamwriter.WriteLine("</html>");
streamwriter.Close();
//end write text
```

Comment: Этот самый простой вариант меня не устраивает. Так мне потребуется генерировать HTML-отчет в виде таблице. Поэтому и хотелось бы узнать как создать HTML-файд с помощью HtmlDocument и HtmlElement

Comment: Почему не работает код:
FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"D:\index.html", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
webBrowser1.DocumentStream = file;
HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document;
HtmlElement elem = doc.CreateElement("TABLE");
doc.Body.AppendChild(elem);

Comment: похоже никто не знает ответа, почему код, взятый с MSDN для работы с HTML, не работает?
PS: вместо file правильно fs, опечатка

Answer (score 2):

Быть может, стоит использовать конструкцию

```
webBrowser1.DocumentStream = fs;
```

Comment: пробовал уже, не получается.

Answer (score 2):

Пример в MSDN замечательно работает. Например так:

1. Этот код (которого в MSDN нет) - вынесем в загрузку формы

   ```
   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"D:\index.html", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
       webBrowser1.DocumentStream = file;
   }
   ```
2. А этот - ну например в обработчик клика

   ```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tmlDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document;
        HtmlElement elem = doc.CreateElement("TABLE");
        doc.Body.AppendChild(elem);
    }
   ```

Проблема в том, что доступ к коду документа появляется только после возникновения события DocumentCompleted

Answer (score 0):

Сам столкнулся с проблемой отчетов. Самый простой(надеюсь он вам подойдет) способ, это сверстать шаблон **html**, и по ключам вставлять туда значения. Использую уже не в первой программе этот способ.

Comment: Сверстать то я сверстал. Но очень неудобно программно искать нужный тег (его начало и конец) и всталять туда дополнительные данные. Хотелось бы так как написано на MSDN: указал в поле какого тега ставить то то, вроде все просто, но блин не работает. Касяк .NET или у меня кривые руки, и видимо я далеко не один такой. Прошу помощи разобраться в данном вопросе. Мне очень много отчетов в HTML надо выводить. Верстать вручную придется еще долго :(

Answer (score 0):

Вот тоже столкнулся с такой проблемой. Прошу не судить строго за решение, но мне подошло.
Создаем класс, в него делаем выборку, потом серилизуем. К получившемуся `.xml` цепляем `xslt`-преобразование и вуаля, получаем на выходе `html`, который цепляем так:

```
webBrowser.Navigate("file:///" + System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ResourceAssembly.Location), "1.xml"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Используй `Linq`  и `XDocument` или `XElement`. Самая легкая работа с документами. Я так иногда небольшие бекапы БД делаю =))

Answer (score 0):

Класс HtmlDocument не содержит конструктора, позволяющего создать пустой документ. Тем не менее, можно это сделать с помощью невидимого WebBrowser:

```
HtmlDocument htmldoc;

//создадим WebBrowser и загрузим в него пустой документ
WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();         
wb.DocumentText = "";
while(wb.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)Application.DoEvents();
/*На практике загрузка пустой строки произойдет очень быстро, поэтому
 можно использовать блокирующий цикл вместо подписки на событие DocumentCompleted*/

//заполним содержимое документа
htmldoc = wb.Document;
htmldoc.Title = "Hello";            

HtmlElement el = htmldoc.CreateElement("h1");
el.InnerText = "Hello, world!";
htmldoc.Body.AppendChild(el);

el = htmldoc.CreateElement("div");
el.InnerText = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.";
htmldoc.Body.AppendChild(el);

//получаем все содержимое документа в виде html
textBox1.Text = htmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("html")[0].OuterHtml;
```

Или добавить ссылку на COM-библиотеку **Microsoft HTML Object Library**, вручную создать экземпляр класса *MSHTML.HTMLDocument* и затем на основе него создать *HtmlDocument* путем вызова его  закрытого конструктора:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace WinFormsTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        /* Создает новый пустой экземпляр HtmlDocument*/
        public static HtmlDocument CreateHtmlDocument()
        {
            Assembly winforms = typeof(Form).Assembly; //System.Windows.Forms

            //создадим служебный класс HtmlShimManager
            Type t = winforms.GetType("System.Windows.Forms.HtmlShimManager");
            object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(t, true);

            //создадим документ и загрузим в него пустую строку
            var doc = new MSHTML.HTMLDocument();
            MSHTML.IHTMLDocument2 doc2 = (MSHTML.IHTMLDocument2)doc;
            doc2.write("");
            doc2.close();

            HtmlDocument htmldoc = null;

            //создаем HtmlDocument с помощью закрытого конструктора
            htmldoc = (HtmlDocument)Activator.CreateInstance(
            typeof(HtmlDocument),
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
            null,
            new object[] { obj, doc },
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            return htmldoc;
        }

        /* Освобождает неуправляемые ресурсы, принадлежащие HtmlDocument*/
        public static void ReleaseHtmlDocument(HtmlDocument doc)
        {
            Type t = typeof(HtmlDocument);
            try
            {
                IDisposable shim = (IDisposable)t.InvokeMember(
                    "shimManager",
                    BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,
                    null, doc, new object[0]);
                shim.Dispose();                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(doc.DomDocument);
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HtmlDocument htmldoc;
            htmldoc    = CreateHtmlDocument(); //создадим документ

            //заполним содержимое документа
            htmldoc.Title = "Hello";

            HtmlElement el = htmldoc.CreateElement("h1");
            el.InnerText = "Hello, world!";
            htmldoc.Body.AppendChild(el);

            el = htmldoc.CreateElement("div");
            el.InnerText = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.";
            el.Style = "color: red";
            htmldoc.Body.AppendChild(el);

            //получаем все содержимое документа в виде html
            textBox1.Text = htmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("html")[0].OuterHtml;

            //освобождаем неуправляемые ресурсы, связанные с HtmlDocument
            ReleaseHtmlDocument(htmldoc);            
        }      

    }   

}
```